# what does -d command with command unzip in shell scripting

Tags: shell

I am using the following command to unzip a file

unzip "/cygdrive/c/auto/-"$new"-test.zip" -d "/cygdrive/c/auto/"

Just want to know the use of  -d "/cygdrive/c/auto/"

what is -d doing here 
 i have searched many web pages but fnd out that it uncompress the file.

Answer (score 1):

From `man unzip`:

```
[-d exdir]
          An optional directory to which to extract  files.   By  default,
          all files and subdirectories are recreated in the current direc-
          tory; the -d option allows extraction in an arbitrary  directory
          (always  assuming one has permission to write to the directory).
          This option need not appear at the end of the command  line;  it
          is also accepted before the zipfile specification (with the nor-
          mal options), immediately after the  zipfile  specification,  or
          between the file(s) and the -x option.  The option and directory
          may be concatenated without any white space  between  them,  but
          note that this may cause normal shell behavior to be suppressed.
          In particular, ``-d ~'' (tilde) is expanded  by  Unix  C  shells
          into  the  name  of  the  user's  home directory, but ``-d~'' is
          treated as a literal subdirectory ``~'' of  the  current  direc-
          tory.
```

Answer (score 0):

-d is your destination directory

Next time, you can use "man unzip" in your ssh.